# Access to symfony services in Behat extension

Tags: symfony, behat

I'm writing a Behat extension meant to be used with Symfony and Symfony2Extension.

For some services, I need to inject services defined in the Symfony application. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In your FeatureContext.php file, you need to implement `KernelAwareInterface` and define `setKernel()` method. Methods `getParameter()` and `getService()` are option and for demonstration purposes.

**Example**

```
namespace Football\TeamBundle\Features\Context;

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareInterface
{
    private $kernel;

    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernelInterface)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernelInterface;
    }

    public function getParameter()
    {
        $myParameter = $this->kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('name_of_the_param');
    }

    public function getService()
    {
        $myService = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('name_of_the_service');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but there you are inside a context. In my case I need to access to them for a service which will be used for an event listener... not in a context